# On a problem about Rolle's theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $f:[1,3]\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $\int_1^2 f(x)dx=2$, and $\int_1^3 f(x)dx=3$, then there exists a real number $c\in(2,3)$ such that
$$
\int_1^c f(x)dx=cf(c)
$$
*Note*. I derived the solution by applying [Rolle's theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) to the function $G(x)=\frac1x\int_1^x f(t)dt$ on the interval $[2,3]$.

Is there any simpler or more interesting proof to this statement?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Perfect case for Rolle

Comment: Problems like this are easy to solve, but giving alternative solution is a hard work....

Comment: This gives a simple generalization of the problem:  Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ where $a>0$, let $\int_a^b f(x)dx=k$, let $h=b-a$, and let $d=\frac{ak}{h}$.  Then there is a number $c\in(a,b)$ such that $\int_a^c f(x)dx=cf(c)-d$.  (In this problem, $a=2, h=1, k=1, d=2$.)